# How can I change the caption format of an image?

Tags: captions

I paste a picture into my document. By default, the caption alignment (Fig. 3) is centered and there is a colon before the caption.

How can I make the label left aligned and change the format from `Fig. 3:` on `Fig. 3`?

My code:

```
\setcounter{figure}{2}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{75_02-45.jpeg}\caption{}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico \documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that ok?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Fig. \thefigure} % Changing the prefix to 'Fig.'
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Example:

\setcounter{figure}{2}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{frog.jpg}
    \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false} % Left align the label
    \caption{} 
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\captionsetup[figure]{
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false, % <<< raggadright also when the caption is shorterthan a single line
  name={Fig.}
  }
```

The complet code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% comment in the final document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false, % <<< raggadright also when the caption is shorterthan a single line
  name={Fig.}
  }

\begin{document}
%\noindent
Example:

\setcounter{figure}{2}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{} 
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]